# Is it possible to override a function defined in an external crate?

Tags: rust, ffi, rust-cargo

I'm trying to use an external crate which defines a pub extern function (let's say "Run_Foo") and is available as a dynamic library entry point.  I'd like to use some of the modules of this external crate, but define my own "Run_Foo" function to be available as the DLL/SO entry point.

The error I'm getting is

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1 
multiple definition of `Run_Foo'.
```

Is there a way to tell the compiler and linker to ignore this particular function from the external create but still allow me to use its sub modules?

Comment: I'm currently working around the issue by using a local copy of the external crate with the library function commented out.

Comment: Is the external crate compiled as a static or dynamic library? How much hacking are you ready to do?

Comment: The crate_type is set as follows:

` crate_type = [ "cdylib", "dylib", "rlib" ] `

This is the library I want to link against:  
` https://github.com/xea/rust-jvmti/ `

And I'm trying to override the Agent_OnLoad function